# How to snap to every second content item in a SwiftUI ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui, layout, swiftui-scrollview

#### Background

At WWDC 2023, Apple introduced a new API for **ScrollViews** that lets us neatly snap views into position with little effort. The following code example snaps the `Rectangle`s into position when the user lifts the finger after a scroll (drag) gesture.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(1..<100) { number in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.mint)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
    }
}
```

#### Question

Now what if I want to only snap to every second `Rectangle` and scroll over the others? Or more generally speaking, how can I control exactly which items (child views) the `ScrollView` should snap to and which one it should ignore for snapping?

It seems like a very trivial thing, but I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this.

#### A Hint?

The documentation for the `scrollTargetLayout(isEnabled:)` modifier states:

> Scroll target layouts act as a convenience for applying a `View/scrollTarget(isEnabled:)` modifier to each views in the layout.

This tells me that there is another modifier called `scrollTarget(isEnabled:)` that I can attach to individual items to granularly enable or disable snapping. However, this modifier doesn't seem to exist. ‍♂️

Is the documentation simply wrong or did I misunderstand it? How can I make this work (without falling back to UIKit)?

Comment: (Please don't tell me it's a private API to be made available to the public in 2029...)

Comment: Have you tried using `.scrollTargetBehavior(...)` with a custom `updateTarget` as described in the docs here:
 [overview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrolltargetbehavior#overview)

Comment: Yes, I have. The problem is that a custom `ScrollTargetBehavior` is very limited to what it can do because it doesn't work with generics. All it gets is a `ScrollTarget` that has an `anchor` point and a `rect`, and a `ScrollTargetBehaviorContext` with general information about the `ScrollView`, but there seems to be no way to pass along information about the item itself.

Comment: well you won't be able to pass `item` to `scrollTargetBehavior()`
 because it is outside of the `ForEach`.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by snap? Do you mean skipping it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's possible to that with the new iOS 17 APIs for ScrollViews. For that you can use the new `.scrollPosition(id: Hashable)` modifier on a scroll view. I have been a bit of fun with it. Here's what I have accomplished so far: [image: Scrolling by two using ActiveID]

Here's the code I've used for it. I'm using an itemCount variable to generate numbers from 1 to 100. As for the non-programatic part I've used the onChange modifier and handled the case there. I've had to use a flag that I've called "onChangedExecuted" because otherwise the event would fire more times then we need.

```
    struct ScrollTransition: View {
    
    // MARK: - UI
    @State private var activeID: Int?
    @State private var selectedStep: Int = 1
    @State private var onChangedExecuted = false
    private var steps: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    private var itemCount: Int = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Move of: \(selectedStep)") {
                withAnimation {
                    if let activeID, (activeID + selectedStep) < itemCount {
                        self.activeID! += selectedStep
                    } else {
                        self.activeID = 1
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Picker("Steps", selection: $selectedStep) {
                ForEach(steps, id: \.self) { step in
                    Text("\(step)")
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            
            Text("Active ID: \(self.activeID ?? 0)")
                .padding(.top, 20)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            
            /// Circular Slider
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 35) {
                    ForEach(1...itemCount, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text("\(index)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundStyle(index == activeID ? .orange : .primary)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal) // <-- I've used this like to center the number (but only one number can appear now)
                    } //: LOOP IMAGES
                } //: HSTACK
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            } //: SCROLL
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            // Snapping
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $activeID)
            .onAppear {
                // Place carousel at the middle item
                activeID = itemCount/2
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            .onChange(of: activeID) { oldValue, newValue in
                guard let oldValue, let newValue,
                        !onChangedExecuted else { return }
                if newValue > oldValue {
                    if ((oldValue + selectedStep) != newValue) {
                        activeID! += (selectedStep - 1)
                        onChangedExecuted = true
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((oldValue - selectedStep) != newValue) {
                        activeID! -= (selectedStep - 1)
                        onChangedExecuted = true
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    onChangedExecuted = false
                }
            }
                
            } //: VSTACK
            .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .bottom)
            
        }
        
    }
```

Modifying the activeID integer number the scroll view will automatically navigate to the element at that index. In this version of the code I've used the new `.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)` to center the activeID text in the middle, not sure you wanted it that way but it seemed the easiest solution to me. Now you can choose with a picker how many items should be "skipped". You can apply the same principle as per your needs.
Hope I was able to help you, and let me know!

Comment: Looks nice! However, it doesn't solve the problem as it only supports programmatic scrolling, doesn't it? The magic of the `.viewAligned` scroll target behavior is that it only allows certain scroll end positions when the _user_ scrolls the scroll view. And it does that in a very smooth way, taking the current scroll velocity and the predicted end location into account. That's the behavior I'm trying to replicate, but not with _every_ view inside the scroll view as an anchor, but only chosen ones. (Think of a ruler that should snap to 5, 10, 15, 20, ... and never to the numbers in between.)

Comment: _Tip:_ While I really appreciate what you've created and you sharing it here, I would recommend to boil down your answers on Stackoverflow to the very essence, i.e. to a minimal example that only solves the problem described by the OP and nothing else. You'll do thousands of developers a great favor as it would otherwise take each of them several minutes to find the part of your answer that's relevant to the problem they're trying to solve.

Comment: You're right, I'll take my time to make the code "thinner", I was having fun like I said XD  But, to the matter at hand, I think it is indeed possible to achieve what you ask for with the solution above. If you use as activeID those numbers you achieve your purpose. ActiveID can range from 1 to any positive number. And the scroll is using a viewAligned behavior like you want, is that correct?

Comment: I've updated the code. No more images are required, it works with just numbers now, and the code is far easier to read, there is no more "weird" stuff going on.

Comment: I've just added the non-programatic behavior too, like you needed, using the onChange modifier at the end of the scrollView. It was the easiest solution that came to my mind :) Let me know, please!