# scrollTo conflict with scrollTargetBehavior?

Tags: swiftui, scroll, ios17

I try to replicate the snapchat camera filters scroll in SwiftUI.

When I scroll manually it's working well thanks to new iOS 17 scroll API, it's centering on each circles. But on tap it's not working, scrollTo method don't keep the center of the circles, I tried many anchors but can't make it work for all circles. Sometimes it's work for the last circles but not the first ones.

Like you can see below, on the beginning of the gif I'm scrolling witg gesture (working), then I tap (not working anymore).

[image]

If I remove scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned) and scrollTargetLayout the scrollTo is working.

Here is a simplified code to reproduce the issue:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct scrollApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            GeometryReader(content: { outerProxy in
                ScrollViewReader(content: { proxy in
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                                Circle()
                                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                    .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                                    .id(index)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        print("tap \(index)")
                                        withAnimation {
                                            proxy.scrollTo(index, anchor: .center)
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, outerProxy.size.width * 0.5 - 100/2)
                        .scrollTargetLayout()
                    }
                    .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                    .overlay {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 10)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                })
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

Only pure SwiftUI solutions will be validated, I already make it works on UIKit.

Comment: You should use `.scrollPosition(id: Binding<(Hashable)?>, anchor: UnitPoint?)` to programmmatically scroll in a `ScrollView` since you are using the new iOS 17 APIs. I made an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77775564/how-to-snap-to-every-second-content-item-in-a-swiftui-scrollview/77782393#77782393).

Comment: I didn't know about this API. I tried but unfortunately I've the same issue, it's not centered as well. Plus it's doesn't animate.

Comment: I'm gonna try it myself and let you know.

Comment: Actually, even using your code the Views are not centered in the middle when tapping on Circles. They are only centered when scrolling. So, it is not an issue of  the `.scrollPosition`.

Comment: Yes that's the thing I'm trying to resolve, I'm just saying scrollPosition doesn't help either.

Comment: I've found a temp working solution. If someone find a better solution tell me because this is quite weird.

I've replaced the scrollTo line in the above code by this:

if index == 0 {
    proxy.scrollTo(index, anchor: .center)
} else {
    proxy.scrollTo(index - 1, anchor: .leading)
 }

I don't use .scrollPosition as its buggy when we tap before the end of animation it's mess up completely the position.

Comment: Well, I'm happy you found a way.